# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Images Compress

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core-mvc, compression

Is there any free and reliable way to compress image files (.jpg/.png) and also create thumbnails in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC?

I tried Bitmap's functions but they throw exceptions like 'System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform'.

Comment: you can add system.drawing by going into the NuGet Package Manager and adding "System.Drawing.Common": https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/6.0.0/

Answer (score 1):

1. ImageSharp is a high-performance, cross-platform image processing
   library for .NET Core. It serves as a modern alternative to
   System.Drawing.Common.
2. With support for multiple image formats and optimized performance,
   it is an excellent choice for handling image-related tasks in
   ASP.NET Core and other .NET Core projects.
3. By integrating the SixLabors.ImageSharp NuGet package, you can
   easily read, write, resize, and perform other image operations in a
   cross-platform manner.

   ```
   using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
   using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

   // Load the image from a file or stream
   using (Image image = Image.Load("path/to/your/image.jpg"))
   {
       // Resize the image to a specific width and height
       int newWidth = 300;
       int newHeight = 200;
       image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(newWidth, newHeight));

       // Save the resized image to a file or stream
       image.Save("path/to/your/resized_image.jpg");
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, but System.Drawing.Common is not supported in ASP.NET CORE 3.1. It throws an exception 'System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform'.

Comment: Try ImageSharp / SkiaSharp / ImageMagick / ImageSharp.Web

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are free and reliable ways to compress image files and create thumbnails in ASP.NET Core without using the System.Drawing.Common library, which is not supported in ASP.NET Core due to platform limitations. Here are two popular and widely used libraries that you can use:

ImageSharp (SixLabors.ImageSharp):
ImageSharp is a cross-platform, high-performance image processing library for .NET that can be used in ASP.NET Core applications. It provides a rich set of features for image manipulation, including resizing, cropping, compression, and more.
To use ImageSharp in your ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application, you need to install the SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web NuGet package.

`Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web`

Here's a sample code snippet to compress an image and generate a thumbnail using ImageSharp:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

public void ProcessImage(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    using (var image = Image.Load(inputFilePath))
    {
        // Resize the image to create a thumbnail
        image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(maxWidth, maxHeight));

        // Compress the image with the specified quality level (e.g., 70)
        var encoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegEncoder { Quality = 70 };

        // Save the thumbnail to the output file
        image.Save(outputFilePath, encoder);
    }
}
```